# не пойму почему блоки slider и images схлопываются

Tags: html, css

```css
#slider .images {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
}

#slider .slide {
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
}

#slider .slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="imeges">
    <div class="slide show">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="imeges">` ошибка в названии класса

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что задано свойство `position: absolute;` и они находятся друг под другом